# Swift closure syntax using { ... in }

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, swiftui

On the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorial: Drawing Paths and Shapes](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes), the following syntax is shown:

```
struct Badge: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
            ...
            }
            .fill(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

I did not see the syntax in the [Swift docs on structs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) and feel very confused.

Additionally, how might one know that `geometry` is "in" the `GeometryReader` statement, whatever that means?

Comment: Wrong chapter. It's in [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simplified syntax of trailing closure, so

```
Path { path in
...
}
```

is just the same as

```
Path( { (path) in
...
})
```

of used `Path` constructor

```
/// Initializes to an empty path then calls `callback` to add
/// the initial elements.
public init(_ callback: (inout Path) -> ())
```

By the way, this syntax is widely used in SwiftUI, so you will see the same in `VStack { .. }`, `GeometryReader { g in ... }`, `ScrollView { ... }` and almost all others UI elements of SwfitUI framework.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with structs. That is closure syntax, where the variable name before `in` is the input argument to the closure.

In the context of SwiftUI, that closure is actually a [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder), which is a specific type of a function builder. You can read more about function readers and the other syntactic sugars that made SwiftUI possible [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-swift-51-features-that-power-swiftuis-api/).

You can learn the type of the closure input argument(s) by option clicking on them in Xcode, just like any other variables. Or you can check the documentation of `GeometryReader` to learn what input arguments its closure accepts.

Comment: Thank you! But I thought you have to explicitly state a return type for closures, even if it is `-> ()`?

Comment: @CalvinXu not sure why did you think that is the case, but that's incorrect. The compiler can infer the return type in most cases, so no need to explicitly state it.